# Print hiera config to multiple lines in config file managed by puppet

Tags: puppet, vagrant

In my yaml file I have multiple values that need to be printed out into an ini file managed by another php module. I can grab the values through heira and output them to the ini file but it's in the wrong format. Each item in the yaml file has to be separated by a line, how do I achieve this?

Here is my yaml file:

```
---
nginx:
  phpini:
    - display_errors = On
    - error_reporting = -1
    - date.timezone = "Europe/London"
    - sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/catchmail"
    - xdebug.default_enable = 1
    - xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
    - xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
    - xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    - xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
    - xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

And this is my manifest why I've tried a few different things without any success:

```
php::ini { 'php.ini':
  value => [
    $nginx['phpini']
  ],
  require => Package["php5-cli"]
}
```

Where value is I need to output each value from phpini to a separate line.

Update:

Here is the template file that's being used:

```
; File Managed by Puppet

<% if @value != "" -%>
<% if @value.is_a? Array -%>
<% @value.each do |name| -%>
<%= name %>
<% end %>
<% else -%>
<%= value %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

So the template supports arrays (I think ruby isn't my strong point) but Heira is concatenating the array from the yaml. Calling the data using `heira_array` makes no difference.

Comment: Does it need to be using `php::ini` or can you have it be a custom template?

Comment: It's already using an erb template (I'll update the question), after digging around a bit more the template does support arrays but heira is concatenating all the items into one string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiera is fetching as an array, but you're passing it to the template as a string with `$nginx['phpini'].join("\n")` - switch to passing the variable directly without manipulating it.

Comment: I tried that (see the commented out line below). Is there another way of specifying it other that $nginx['phpini']?

Comment: How is that being retrieved from Hiera?

Comment: Via - $nginx = hiera('nginx', false)

Comment: Did you have it set to `value => [ $nginx['phpini'] ],` or `value => $nginx['phpini'],`?  You should just pass it in directly, without wrapping it in an additional array.

Comment: like the first one will try the second.

Comment: Second one works brilliantly thanks! If you update your question with the answer then I'll accept.